# Pros and cons of rooting using apps ("Soft Root") compared to other methods ("Hard Root")

Tags: rooting, security, malware, unrooting, antivirus

There are quite a few app based rooting methods. A recent review [9 free software apps to root Android devices](http://www.3ptechies.com/mobile/android/9-best-software-apps-to-root-android-devices.html), points to some of them and there may be more apps, paid or otherwise.

From what I understand,

**Plus Points**

1. Ease of rooting
2. Don't need a laptop or computer

**Minuses**

1. Based on exploits, so may not work if exploits are denied by OS updates
2. Difficulty in unrooting (as I see on some forums for my device Huawei Honor 6)

**Questions:**

- What are the pros and cons apart from above?
- If a device has both options - app based rooting and rooting by methods by developers, which one should I opt for?

**Note:** I am not seeking app suggestion or recommendation.

Comment: My personal take has always been to stay away from app based rooting as long as a working custom recovery is available and can be flashed from bootloader. The very existence of 1-click root apps and successful implementation  of them for a device  implies that the device has a severe vulnerability (which may be exploited by an app, should it need to) which has not been patched by its user or by its  developer (OEM). That said, my first rooting was done using a 1-click root app (Framaroot). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to AndrewT who posted a [link on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29235107#29235107), having this research paper  as a refernce in one of the [answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/121253/99059). This answer is entirely based on the this paper (May 2015) and highlights common user understandable aspects ( it has a lot of *security* related material for those interested)

---

> - What are the pros and cons apart from above?
> - If a device has both options - app based rooting and rooting by methods by developers, which one should I opt for?

**Answer:**  It's all about malware vulnerability. Using Root exploits is a HUGE security risk and that over-weighs any other advantages

### What is Soft Root and Hard Root?

- **Soft Root :**  Root is obtained directly by
  running a piece of software (i.e., root exploits)- either by directly installing on the device or  requiring `adb` shell through a PC connection
- **Hard Root :**  Root is obtained by flashing su binary externally via an update package or ROM

### Malware Threat - in general

- Even though legitimate, many convenient one-click root methods operate by exploiting vulnerabilities in the Android system. If not carefully controlled, such exploits can be abused by malware author to gain unauthorized root privilege.
- As described in the Android Malware *Genome Project*  ,  **36.7% ( of 1260 ) malware samples had embedded at least one root exploit.**
- These well-engineered exploits are not well protected, it is extremely dangerous if they fall in the wrong hands.

### Who are major root providers  and broadly, how does it work?

[image]

### What are the types of root expolits ?

The paper covers 78 exploits studied. In general , the order of **impact** ( from the *highest to lowest*) :

- **Kernel Exploits:** Due to its privileged position, targeting Linux Kernel is natural to achieve full control over an Android device- example ,TowelRoot
- **Library Exploits:** the exploits targeting libraries that are used by Android system processes, or external libraries used for supporting different applications, example ZergRush exploit , libsysutils used by Volume Manager daemon
- **Application and Application Framework Application layer root exploits :** exploits targeting system applications or services, mostly include vulnerable logics introduced by `setuid` utilities, system applications, or services. example is a vulnerable `setuid` utility that is only present on XoomFE devices
  that has a command injection vulnerability
- **Vendor-Specific Kernel or Drivers:** Vendors either customize the kernel (e.g., Qualcomm’s custom Linux kernel branch) or provide vendor-specific device drivers for various peripherals (e.g., camera, sound). Such code runs inside the kernel space and the compromise of which can also lead to full control over the device.

**Number wise** , exploits are as in figure below

[image]

### How difficult is it to lay your hands on Exploit (Source or Binary) ?

**Very easy.** Easily available from Google search, making it a cake walk  for malware authors to leverage such exploits. Googling for 73 exploits lead to 68 of them being available - 46 with source code and 22 with binaries

### How do these exploits work?

Major requirements for exploits to work (ordered from *most difficult  to least*) ( [malware](/questions/tagged/malware) tag has a lot of these instances)

- **Requiring user interactions:** (6 out of 78 studied)

  - Asking the user to download an app and manually interrupt the installation
  - Asking the user to boot into recovery at least once .
  - Asking the user to manually put the device into “battery
    saving” mode .
  - Asking  the user to open a vendor specific app and hit a button
- **Requiring `adb` shell through a PC connection:** (17 out of 78 studied). For some exploits, `adb` shell connection is required because of the following most common reasons:

  - The exploit can successfully modify a setting in `local.prop` which enables root for `adb` shell only.
  - The exploit needs to write to a file owned by group shell and group-writable (not world-writable)
  - The exploit targets the adb daemon process that requires the attack process to run with shell user. For instance, the *Rage Against the Cage exploit* targets the vulnerability of adb daemon’s missing check on return value of `setuid()`
- **Reboot:** (6 out of 78 studied)  Generally, many root exploits require at least one reboot. For instance, a symbolic link attack would allow an attacker to delete a file owned by system with weak permission, to setup a link at the same location to a protected file. After a reboot, the corresponding init scripts would attempt to change the permission of the original file  to world-writable, which in reality changes the permission of the linked file
- **None or permission:**  (44 out of 78 studied) The exploits in this category have no hard requirements, however, some of them may require certain Android permissions like `READ LOGS` in order for the process owner to be placed in certain user group.

### Can these exploits be detected by Anti-Virus ?

Since the root exploits are highly sensitive and may be leveraged by various Android malware, it is expected that anti-virus software on Android platform can identify most of them, including the ones implemented by root providers. Overall, the result shows that the state-of-the-art security products on Android platform still **cannot address root exploits effectively**

4 representative Android anti-virus products  were used to test the *largest provider (name not revealed)* having 167 exploits. Because originally downloaded exploits from the providers  database have packed the actual exploit code and employed a tamper-detection mechanism, study crafted 3 different versions for every exploit:

1. Original exploit fetched directly from providers servers, with
   packing and tamper-detection on.
2. Unpacked exploit, which will expose all actual exploit logic to
       anti-virus products.
3. Re-packed exploit with tamper-detection disabled.

Exploit binaries engineered by large root providers are surprisingly **“clean”** as all major anti-virus software have difficulty detecting them as table below shows

[image]

### Conclusion

Simple. Stay away from *Soft Root methods* unless you are capable of dealing with the consequences

Comment: I feel like you're missing the point about exploits here. If your phone has a vulnerability which a "soft root" can use, malware can exploit that vulnerability regardless of whether you use it or not. Rooting your phone by exploiting a vulnerability doesn't make it more vulnerable.

Comment: @DanHulme: Agreed that it doesn't increase vulnerability.  I asked the question initially to understand , *why and which (soft / hard root)* is better - to that extent,  there is an answer (not withstanding existence of vulnerability). However, if you feel the answer can be improved incorporating your view, please feel free to do so

Comment: I just don't think that what you're saying about the danger of these vulnerabilities has any bearing at all on the question of which method to choose.

Comment: By choosing *soft root*, it looks like one is *inviting* exploitation of vulnerabilities but yes I think I get what you are saying

Comment: It's like the following question and answer. "I have a front door with a key, and a back door which I never lock. Which should I use to get into my house?" "You shouldn't use the unlocked back door because a burglar might get in that way." The door is unlocked whether you use it or not.

Comment: Nice analogy. Apt. More one tries to understand security, more one realizes  how less protected

Answer (score 5):

There are a few advantages to rooting using the official process.

1. It's officially supported on many phones. This means you can use a process that's documented by the manufacturer, and tools from an official source, or a trustworthy third party (CWM or TWRP), instead of having to run a tool that you got from some dodgy website.
2. Because it's officially supported, most of the time, a system update won't change the process, so you don't need to go looking around for "the latest" rooting method. In contrast, software updates tend to patch vulnerabilities, so exploit methods will often stop working after an update.
3. Because of the above, after you "soft root" you might be tempted to not install a system update, because that update patches the vulnerability and stops your rooting method working. With the official process, there's no reason to stay on an old, vulnerable version.

As well as the convenience of a one-click method (mentioned in the question), there are some other advantages of doing it that way instead.

1. Unlocking the bootloader to "hard root" wipes the phone, so you have to set things up again and restore data from backup. Typically "soft rooting" via a vulnerability doesn't need to wipe the phone, and that can be a lot more convenient.
2. Because rooting modifies the system partition, typically you can't do an OTA update afterwards: the updater recognises the system is modified, and bails out. But **some** "soft root" methods on **some phones** avoid this problem, so you can do an OTA update without having to unroot or flash a new system image. This is also a bit easier. Either way, you'll still have to root again after an update.
3. Since you don't have to unlock the bootloader, there's no temptation to leave it unlocked. This has the security benefit that people can't flash new ROMs to your phone (e.g. if it is stolen and they want to circumvent the screen lock or factory reset protection).

What Beeshyams says about security is important, but to my mind it's irrelevant to the question. It's good to point out or remind people that every "soft rooting" method is exploiting a security vulnerability, and malware could use just the same vulnerability to install rootkits on your phone. However, the vulnerability is there whether you use it or not. The security risk comes from the **possibility** of the rooting method. Rooting your phone by exploiting the vulnerability doesn't make it more exploitable, or worse.

If your phone **can be rooted** by a rooting app/exploit, then it is vulnerable to malware. This is true just the same regardless of whether you root it or what method you use. Not using the exploit (by doing a "hard root" instead, or just by not rooting) will **not** protect you from malware, **nor** will it reduce your exposure.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>On request by OP, some details [from chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26321102#26321102):</sup>

Good question, but hard to answer: there are a few more things to consider.

1. it's not just "app based versus USB" – and even your "Difficulty in unrooting" is not necessarily the fault of "app based" in general, but rather that of a specific app causing that difficulty.
2. From a security point of view: if there's an app that can root my device – who says another app doesn't just do that without my consent? We all know there's malware out there doing exactly that (in order to integrate itself as system app, to be protected against factory-reset).
3. However, if there's no such app (and in the hope that's because it cannot be done by an app on this device/ROM), it's much harder for such malware. If then there's an easy method via USB, I feel a little safer :) It's rather unlikely some other app manages to attach an USB cable, download something to my computer, and runs that combo to do harm.

So above might count as "contra app-based" – but if such an app already exists for the device in question, there's not much we can do about. Even if we say "it's safer the other way round", that doesn't protect us against #2. Sure, we can check that before buying a device – but who says such an app doesn't pop up the day after?