# Do i need the internet to root my android device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Have been trying to root without the intent and it seems it's not working, I have tried every thing, using different applications still the same thing so that's why I'm asking..

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need the internet to root a device, just to download the ROMs in the first place (and maybe to get a bootloader unlocking code before unlocking the bootloader, if you have an HTC phone).

It's entirely possible that some "one-click root" apps might refuse to run without an internet connection, but that's nothing to do with the rooting process itself: it's just that app. A ["hard root" by flashing the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131690/12442) doesn't use those apps, and it will definitely work without either the PC or the phone connected to the internet.